# Is the Query returning in consistent results?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Changed the question after peeling the outer layers

I am using MySQL 5.1

```
select s.status, street, m.meterpointid
from meterpoint m inner join account a
     on ( m.accountid = a.accountid) inner join
     meterservice s
     on ( m.meterpointid = s.meterpointid )
where a.citystateid=1 and m.meterpointid=3008 and m.lastupdate is not null 
group by status, street ;
```

The above query returns

```
1   210 S HWY 3 3008
```

---

```
select s.status, street, m.meterpointid
from meterpoint m inner join account a
     on ( m.accountid = a.accountid) inner join
     meterservice s
     on ( m.meterpointid = s.meterpointid )
where a.citystateid=1 and m.lastupdate is not null 
group by status, street ;
```

but the output from above query which is exactly the same as the previous query without the `m.meterpointid=3008` does not contain the `1   210 S HWY 3 3008`

Any ideas?

Thanks
Naren

Answer (score 0):

The change on the inner query is changing the count in the outer query, so `having count(*) = 1` is no longer true. I find the best way to diagnose these sorts of things is to peel away outer layers and look at the inner queries until I figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is not at all surprising.  You are using a (mis)feature of MySQL called *Hidden Columns*.  That is, you have columns in the `select` clause that are not in the `group by` clause and are not in aggregation functions.

In this case, an arbitrary value is chosen for the value.

To fix this problem, either do:

```
group by status, street, m.meterpointid
```

or

```
select s.status, street, min(m.meterpointid)
```

These will fix the query so the results are determinate.

Answer (score -1):

Not including the test `m.meterpointid=3008` can change the count. If, according to `count(*) = 1`, the count is not `1` the result is discarded. If the subselect of the second query returns more than one record, then this result will be discarded.

Comment: Thanks. The first query returns only one row too.

Comment: The question is whether the inner most select returns more than one record for the street `3008 210 S HWY 3` in the second query. Try running only `select s.status, street, m.meterpointid
              from meterpoint m
                   inner join account a on ( m.accountid = a.accountid)
                   inner join meterservice s on ( m.meterpointid = s.meterpointid )
              where a.citystateid=1 and m.lastupdate is not null
              group by status, street`

Comment: Did that.. and the inner most select is not returning the row.. I have reposted the question.

Comment: Basically I had to include "meterpointid" in the inner most group by and the all the outer most group by's to get it working